# modalpopupextender gridview paging not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, asp.net-ajax

> GridView paging in modalpopupextender issue
>   :
>   I have a  GridView in modalpopupextender...but the thing is Paging is not working inside it....
>
> My HTML code is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:gridview runat="server" id="GridView2" showfooter="true" 
    autogeneratecolumns="false" GridLines="None" CssClass="table" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" RowStyle-CssClass="td" Width="100%" 
    OnRowCreated="GridView2_RowCreated"   >
    <columns>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Date" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Date_Select"  Text='<%#Eval("Date","{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' onclick="Date1_Click" EnableTheming="False"></asp:LinkButton>


</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>

</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


         <asp:boundfield datafield="" headertext="Total" footerstyle-font-bold="true" 
            footertext="Grand Total:" >
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>

        <asp:boundfield datafield="MIns" headertext="Mins" 
            footerstyle-font-bold="true"   >
 <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="Amount" headertext="Amount" footerstyle-font-bold="true" 
             >
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>

        <asp:boundfield datafield="Profit" headertext="Profit"  
            footerstyle-font-bold="true">
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>

   </columns>

 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CEFF99" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="#C1FF80" BorderStyle="Solid" 
              BorderWidth="1px"></HeaderStyle>

 <RowStyle CssClass="td"></RowStyle>
</asp:gridview>


<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnModalPopUp1" 
        style="display:none"/>


 <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopUpExtender2" 
         runat="server"
         TargetControlID="btnModalPopUp1"
         PopupControlID="pnlPopUp1"
         BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="btnCancel1" X="570" Y="10"
        >
 </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2">
     <ProgressTemplate>
      <div class="modal">
        <div class="center" align="center">
          This can take a while. Please be patient...
          <img alt="" src="Images/loader.gif" />
         </div>
       </div>
      </ProgressTemplate>
     </asp:UpdateProgress>


 <asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="pnlPopUp1" CssClass="modalPopup">
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancel1" 
         Text="Close"/>
 <asp:gridview runat="server" id="GridView18" showfooter="true" 
    autogeneratecolumns="false" GridLines="None" CssClass="table" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" RowStyle-CssClass="td" Width="100%" 
    AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10" 
    EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True"   >
     <columns>

        <asp:boundfield datafield="Customer" headertext="Customer" 
            footerstyle-font-bold="true"   >
  <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>


         <asp:boundfield datafield="MIns" headertext="Mins" footerstyle-font-bold="true" >
 <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="Amount" headertext="Amount" 
            footerstyle-font-bold="true"   >
 <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="Profit" headertext="Profit" footerstyle-font-bold="true" 
             >
 <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
        </asp:boundfield>



    </columns>

 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CEFF99" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="#C1FF80" BorderStyle="Solid" 
              BorderWidth="1px"></HeaderStyle>

   <RowStyle CssClass="td"></RowStyle>
 </asp:gridview>
 </asp:Panel>



</ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "GridView18" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />

  </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> This is my Code Behind for Paging:

```
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView18.DataSource = ds;
    GridView18.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView18.DataBind();
    modalPopUpExtender2.Show();

     }
```

> Any help is highly appreciated ...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

First: if you go to [MSDN concerning UpdatePanels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) and scroll down to the section:

**Controls that Are Not Compatible with UpdatePanel Controls**

You find this:

> - GridView and DetailsView controls when their EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks property is set to true.

Paging a Gridview requires a Postback.  Typically when you use any kind of modal/popup control it uses JS to activate.  But a postback is going eliminate the popup...so...

The main thing is you need to be able to maintain the popup state between postbacks. There are a couple of ways to handle this.

Easiest is to eliminate the paging and use scrolling, assuming the total number of items is a manageable list.  If the list is too long chances are that it's also too much information for a user anyway and should be filtered to a manageable list.

If you must use paging, you need to use a popup control that can withstand postbacks, which may mean using an `<iframe>`.  I don't know enough about the AjaxControlToolkit to say if it can be done that way.

Personally, when I needed to do what you are trying to do via popup, I use [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).  **But this also requires jquery**.

I move the gridview to a standalone page and configure Colorbox to open the page in an iframe.  This way the iframe manages the paging postbacks.